# Notation to define property of a no yet defined function

Tags: functions, notation

I'm developing a method where the user has to define a problem-dependent function $p: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that will later be used as a condition:

$p(a,b) = 0$

I now want to ensure that both $a$ and $b$ are contained in the function definition. How do I write this down?
The way I'm doing it right now is:

$p:  \mathbb{R}^{n} \times  \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R} \qquad \nabla_{a} p \neq 0  \qquad  \nabla_{b} p \neq 0$

Such that, for example $p(a,b) = b^T b$ is not allowed but $p(a,b) = a^T b$ is.

How would you write this? Is there anything wrong with my notation?

Comment: What do I have to search for to find an answer to this question?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to ensure that both $a$ and $b$ are contained in the function definition?

Comment: @md2perpe i want to integrate an ODE from a starting point $x(0) = a$ up to an endpoint $b$ such that $a,b$ satisfy $p(a,b) = 0$. Fo example, to simulate one period of an oscillating system $p(a,b) = b - a = 0$.

Comment: Saying $\nabla_a p\neq 0$ requires $p$ to be differentiable. A more general way is to say that $p(\cdot,b) : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ may not be constant for fixed $b$.